# Why am I getting code 400 response instead of error json object in tomcat 9 with spring 5?

Tags: java, tomcat9, spring5

The controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Validated
public class ApiController {


    @PostMapping(value = "/in",
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    ResponseEntity<InitResponse> inPost(
            @ApiParam(required = true) @Valid @RequestBody InRequest inRequest) {
        LOG.info("inPost request was received = {}", inRequest);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
    }
```

The exception handler:

```
@ControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = ApiController .class, annotations = RestController.class)
public class InExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<INErrors> handleConstraintViolation(ConstraintViolationException ex) {

        LOG.info("handleConstraintViolation was trigerred");
        INError INError = new INError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.toString(), ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new INErrors(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<INErrors> handleMethodArgumentConstraintViolation(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {

        BindingResult result = ex.getBindingResult();
        List<FieldError> fieldErrors = result.getFieldErrors();

        return new ResponseEntity<>(processFieldErrors(fieldErrors), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

If the InRequest has all fields within the javax validation constraint then I get the right code, but when a field doesn't match validation I just get 400 response code.
There are other exception handlers defined but I've put breakpoints everywhere and nothing is triggered.

I also added the log4j property:

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod=DEBUG,stdout
```

but this didn't produce any additional output when debugging.
I'm expecting to also to have the INErrors object sent back, but it doesn't even enter either one of the 2 handling methods.

Comment: By _"I just get 400 response code"_ do you mean you get a 400 response code (as requested), but with an **empty** body?

Comment: the response doesn't have the INErrors object that I'm trying to send back with the wrong fields, I'll update the question,thx

Comment: Is it truly 400 (bad request) or 404 (bad URL)?

Comment: yes, it's just 400, without any more details, with the right fields set on the InRequest object, it's fine

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because Spring's default exception handler handles all WebMvc's standard exceptions by itself and then delegates unhandled exceptions to user-defined `@ExceptionHandler` methods.

In your case `@Valid` constraint violation throws Spring's `MethodArgumentNotValidException` which is handled by `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler#handleMethodArgumentNotValid`. So, to change the default behaviour for this exception, you need to override this method in your `@ControllerAdivce`.

```
@ControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = ApiController .class, annotations = RestController.class)
public class InExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        BindingResult result = ex.getBindingResult();
        List<FieldError> fieldErrors = result.getFieldErrors();

        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(processFieldErrors(fieldErrors));
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: I saw that you're using both `assignableTypes` and `annotations` for `@ControllerAdvice` exception handler. This makes Spring register one exception handler for all `@RestController`s. Try using either `assignableTypes` or `annotations`.

As an option, you can create your custom annotation for different exception handlers.

Following code prints "one" when invalid data supplied to `/one` and "two" when data was sent to "/two".

```
@RestController
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface One {}

@RestController
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Two {}

@One
class ControllerOne {

    @PostMapping("one")
    String a(@RequestBody @Valid Data data) {
        return data.value;
    }
}

@Two
class ControllerTwo {

    @PostMapping("two")
    String a(@RequestBody @Valid Data data) {
        return data.value;
    }
}

@ControllerAdvice(annotations = One.class)
class HandlerOne extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("one");
    }
}

@ControllerAdvice(annotations = Two.class)
class HandlerTwo extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("two");
    }
}
```

Comment: I already have another handler that extends it and overrides the method, so now I have an ambigous definition exception on startup, but that handler isn't being called either

Comment: @osmingo, please, try changing your handlers as described in edited answer

Comment: I added one annotation for my controller and another for the rest of the controllers but I'm still getting that same ambigous definition exception at startup

Comment: Could you please provide reproducible example of this issue? And also specify your spring and spring boot versions?

Comment: spring boot version is 2.3.7 and spring version 5.2.13, I'm deploying to a tomcat 9.0.30

Comment: @osmingo, just checked my solution on spring boot 2.3.7 and it works as expected. Could you please share the code sample and exception you're getting?

Comment: there's a lot of config in the project, and it would take a long time to extract it, I'll dig around some more

Comment: I think that problem may occur when you're autowiring `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler ` to one of your classes. Try autowiring not only by class but also by name of the bean.

Comment: putting the method in the controller worked for me, also those annotations add a lot of unnecessary code

Answer (score 0):

The javax annotation style validation for the model worked for me only when I added the method inside the controller :

```
public class ApiController {
...
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<INErrors> handleConstraintViolation(MethodArgumentNotValidException exception) {
        BindingResult result = exception.getBindingResult();
        List<FieldError> fieldErrors = result.getFieldErrors();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(processFieldErrors(fieldErrors), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```